# Number of permutations with subset distance constraint

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, constraints

The problem is to calculate the number of all unique permutations of a string with repetitions. There is also a constraint for one subset elements to be spaced from each other.

Typical input data is **AAAAAABBBCCCC**. Lets assign to *L* the length of input string.

The goal is to find the number of all possible permutations of this string, in which any two **C**'s *must not to* be placed next each other.

As I understand, the problem can be splitted into 2 subproblems:

1. Count number of unique permutations of **AAAAAABBB** (N1);
2. Count number of *correct* possible placements of all (4 in our case) **C**'s in *L* (N2);
3. Multiply N1 and N2 to get the answer.

N1 can be calculated as:
`L!/(La! * Lb!)`.

How should I calculate N2? I'm not interested in direct answer, just looking for some clarification. My attempt on manual synthesis of the formula was very awful (because we have multiple intervals, and at every element task splits into two).

Do this kind of task is likely to be solved by dynamic programming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a well-posed first question. We expect on math.stackexchange that you share your thoughts about the problem, and you have done that nicely (sharing thoughts is so importantly that you can even get downvotes for not sharing them). Next to that, the question is self-contained and it is clear what is being asked. Keep asking such well-posed questions!

Comment: Compliments are not neccessary :). I have rich experience working with other StackExchange forums :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a string of $m$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s into which we wish to insert $k$ $C$'s such that no two $C$'s are consecutive.  As you correctly concluded, there are $\binom{m + n}{n}$ strings of $m$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s.  The $k$ $C$'s can be inserted in the $m + n - 1$ spaces between consecutive letters of the string of $m$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s or in the two spaces at the end of the string, giving us $m + n - 1 + 2 = m + n + 1$ spaces where we can place the $k$ $C$'s.  Thus, we can place the $C$'s in $\binom{m + n + 1}{k}$ ways. Note that if $k > m + n + 1$, $\binom{m + n + 1}{k} = 0$, as we would expect since using more than $m + n + 1$ $C$'s would require us to use at least two consecutive $C$'s.  Hence, there are $$\binom{m + n}{n}\binom{m + n + 1}{k}$$ strings with $m$ $A$'s, $n$ $B$'s, and $k$ $C$'s in which no two $C$'s are consecutive.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It is a very nice way to think about the problem as combintation of _spaces_. However, this solution can't be generalized (at least, i don't have an idea by now) for the cases with other minimal distance between elements (>2) required.